# How to upload image file using ReactJS to api using NestJS with bytea datatype

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, file-upload, nestjs

I want to know how can I properly upload a file using ReactJS to api using NestJS, so far here is what I have done

in API's swagger, here is the post method for file upload

[image]

This is the table from PostgreSQL for that entity

[image]

The api is created using this crud typeorm [@nestjsx/crud-typeorm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjsx/crud-typeorm)

And in my ReactJS code, currently I have this page:

```
    const EditBadge = () => {
      const { id } = useParams();
    
      const history = useNavigate();
      const [data, setData] = useState({
        id: "",
        badge_name: "",
        badge_description: "",
        img_icon: "",
      });
    
      const [baseImage, setBaseImage] = useState("");
    
      const { badge_name, badge_description, img_icon } = data;
    
      const onInputChange = (e: any) => {
        setData({ ...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      };
    
      const onSubmit = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        await api.patch(`badges/${id}`, data);
        history("/badge");
      };
    
      const loadData = async () => {
        const result = await api.get(`badges/${id}`);
        setData(result.data);
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
      }, []);
    
      const uploadImage = async (e: any) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const base64 = await convertBase64(file);
        setBaseImage(String(base64));
      };
    
      const convertBase64 = (file: any) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    
          fileReader.onload = () => {
            resolve(fileReader.result);
          };
    
          fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
            reject(error);
          };
        });
      };
    
      return (
        <Container className="create-badge-container">
          <Container className="create-badge-content">
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <div className="img-container text-center">
                  <Image
                    className="p-2"
                    src={baseImage}
                    alt=""
                    width={198}
                    height={219}
                  />
                </div>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Form className="create-badge-form" onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
                  <Row className="pt-4">
                    <Col className="col-4">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Badge Name"
                        aria-label="Badge Name"
                        name="badge_name"
                        value={badge_name}
                        onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
                      />
                    </Col>
                    <Col className="col-4">
                      <input
                        className="form-control"
                        type="file"
                        id="file"
                        accept=".jpeg, .png, .jpg"
                        name="img_icon"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          uploadImage(e);
                        }}
                      />
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Row className="pt-4">
                    <Col className="col-8">
                      <textarea
                        className="form-control"
                        id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
                        placeholder="Description"
                        rows={3}
                        name="badge_description"
                        value={badge_description}
                        onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
                      ></textarea>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Row className="pt-5">
                    <Col className="col-4">
                      <Button type="submit" className="btn-create">
                        Update
                      </Button>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </Form>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </Container>
      );
    };

export default EditBadge;
```

So far this is what I've got base on research, and I got stuck and have no idea how can I post/create this with the uploaded image file

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you prefer to do things me in my case I used axios and the FormData class

my reactjs code

```
import React,{ ChangeEvent, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


const UploadFile = () => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState<any>();

    const onChange = (file: ChangeEvent) => {
        const { files } = file.target as HTMLInputElement;
        if (files && files.length !== 0) {
          setFile(files[0]);
        }
    }

    const handleUpload = async () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file)
        const upload = await axios({
            url:"http://localhost:4000/upload",
            method:"post",
            headers:{
                Authorization: `Bearer your token`
            },
            data:formData
        }).then(r => r);

        console.log(upload);
        
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
                <input type="file" onChange={onChange} />
                <button onClick={handleUpload}>upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UploadFile
```

and my nestjs code

```
import { Controller, Post, UploadedFile, UseGuards, UseInterceptors } from "@nestjs/common";
import { diskStorage } from "multer";
import { randomUUID } from 'crypto';
import Path = require('path');
import { FileInterceptor} from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from "src/auth/guard/jwt.auth.guard";
const storage = {
    storage : diskStorage({
        destination: 'src/uploads/files',
        filename: (req, file, cb) =>{
            const filename: string = 'myfile-' + randomUUID();
            const extension: string = Path.parse(file.originalname).ext;
            cb(null, `${filename}${extension}`)
        }
    })
}

@Controller('upload')
export class UploadController {

    // @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard) your methode of guard
    @Post()
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', storage))
    uploaiFile(
        @UploadedFile() file:any
    ){
        console.log(file)
        return file
    }
}
```